# Using filterConfig.yml with DocFX

Tags: docfx

I am new to DocFx and I am trying to configure DocFx to filter out DataSet information from a project and no matter how I enter it - it just doesn't work.

The filterConfig.yml file has the following entries:

```
apiRules:
- exclude:
  uidRegex: '^PhoenixControls\.Data\.AirStationDataSet'
- exclude
  uidRegex: '^PhoenixControls\.Data\.ProductionOrderData'
- exclude:
  uidRegex: '^PhoenixControls\.Data\.ReferenceDataSet'
```

Running docfx docfx.json --serve

Serves up the following error:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2jQp.png)

If I remove two of the -excludes - It will not error out - but it doesn't remove the objects I am trying to filter out.

What is the magic I need to perform to get object to filter out of DocFx?

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing trailing ':' in line 5.

```
apiRules:
- exclude:
  uidRegex: '^PhoenixControls\.Data\.AirStationDataSet'
- exclude:
  uidRegex: '^PhoenixControls\.Data\.ProductionOrderData'
- exclude:
  uidRegex: '^PhoenixControls\.Data\.ReferenceDataSet'
```

Give VS Code with the [YAML exension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml) a try to edit YAML. It will highlight such mistakes:
[image]